How does a leaf spring behave with a pivot?
I'm having a hard time visualizing how a leaf spring would behave under a specific scenario:

Suppose we have a homogenous leaf spring that is fixed in space at a single location (black dot above).
If the spring is unable to rotate around this fixed point, I believe that the force required for A to deflect the spring is smaller than the force required for B, because the length of spring acting on A is larger. This seems fairly obvious to me, so hopefully my intuition is not completely flawed!
The question I have is: What happens when the spring is allowed to pivot around the fixed point? Does it still require more force for B to deflect the spring (when A is fixed) than when A deflects it (and B is fixed)? My intuition is that both scenarios should require the same amount of force, since the spring rotating around its fixed point will transfer forces from one side of the fixed point to the other.
